# Curious Scan Behaviour (Zxing)

Tags: java, zxing

I currently try to detect QR-Codes inside an large (vertical large) image.

When I pass the large image into the ZXing .decode() I get a NotFoundException. 
I read somewhere that an image can only have a certain size/height and so I wrote a kind of "walker" that divides the image and then searches and decodes the QR code.

The system works quite well but Zxing doesn't play along.

During my tests with the system I produced three images and one of them is working to extract the qr code.

Image 1 (NotWorking => NotFoundException):

**Resolution**: 999x648.
**Size**: 329.09 kB
[image]

Image 2 (Working => Correct Output):

**Resolution**: 999x714
**Size**: 357.41 kB
[image]

Image 3 (Not Working => NotFoundException)

**Resolution**: 999x800
**Size**: 391.86 kB

[image]

The Code for decoding is as simple as the images.

```
BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImageWalker)));
qrCodeResult = multiFormatReader.decode(binaryBitmap);
```

When I change the MultiFormatReader to a QRCodeReader, I get a

```
com.google.zxing.ChecksumException
```

Comment: What is the question

Comment: How to solve this problem. 1 of the three QR Codes is decodable but all of them are the same except the height